# Инициализация переменной в PHP

Tags: php

Писал код писал...потом подумал я же все время перед тем как использовать переменную всегда делаю присвоение значением того типа который мне нужен. Почитал мануал для уверенности, проведя несколько тестов возникли вопросы:

1. Если мы используем неинициализированную переменную мы словим `Notice`, хотя в мануале написано что использовать неинициализированные переменные это очень хорошая практика, где?(Возможно это криво написано в мануале, возможно имелось ввиду наоборот)
2. Если мы попытаемся к неициализированной переменной сделать допустим конкатенацию, мы словим `Notice`, хотя если мы напишем переменной изначально `NULL`, то `Notice` мы не словим, хотя опять же если мы выведем неинициализированную переменную через `var_dump` мы получим `NULL`...выходит в одном случае есть `Notice`, а в другом нет, почему?
3. Если мы присвоим переменной значение `NULL` будет ли считаться что переменная инициализированна? А если мы просто напишем переменную и в конце поставим точку с запятой будет ли это являться тем что переменная неинициализированна?(В мануале ни разу не видел чтобы просто писали переменную без присвоения)

   P.S Если я вспомню еще какие-то вопросы по этой теме отпишу...я не знаю возможно мои вопросы связаны с тем что я не понимаю тип `NULL`?

Comment: `в мануале написано что использовать неинициализированные переменные это очень хорошая практика, где?` ....... действительно, где? Укажите пожалуйста источник и где конкретно это написано

Comment: @АлексейШиманский  http://php.net/manual/ru/language.variables.basics.php
почти в самом низу

Comment: *Хотя в PHP и нет необходимости инициализировать переменные, это считается очень хорошей практикой.* - вы про это? Так тут как раз наоборот говорится о том, что хорошая практика - инициализировать!

Comment: Вы просто неправильно растолковали предложение))   нет необходимости инициализировать переменные, НО считается очень хорошей практикой делать это... примерно вот так надо читать

Comment: @PinkTux Значит я неправильно понял =) Иногда так пишут что не понимаешь что вообще происходит

Comment: Блин хотел автору ответа написать, а он дропнул ответ видать из-за первого вопроса

Comment: __Иногда так пишут что не понимаешь что вообще происходит__. Поправил. С вечерним билдом должно накатиться.

Comment: @rjhdby будет замечательно! И еще там в документации много косяков связанных с тем что некоторые вещи были описаны для старых версий, а некоторые вещи для более новых...иногда сидишь и недоумеваешь как так-то? Указать что именно косячно точно не могу ибо последнее что я видел это была инициализация констант в классе и там было написано что ошибка будет если написать мат.выражение, но в том месте поправили, что радует =)

Comment: @MaximPro [всё в ваших руках](http://php.net/get-involved.php)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Для начала - тип null

NULL - это единственно возможное значение типа null.

Переменная считается null, если:

- ей была присвоена константа NULL.
- ей еще не было присвоено никакого значения.
- она была удалена с помощью unset().

### Почему вообще это работает

Интерпретатор PHP использует позднее связывание(динамическая типизация - переменные связываются с типом в момент присвоения значения), потому возможно выполнение кода с переменными, которые никогда не были объявлены.

Но тем не менее между явно *объявленной null-переменной* и *не объявленной*  разница есть!

### Неинициализированная, NULL, пустая и заданная переменная

```
$null = NULL; // заданная null
$empty = ""; // заданная и пустая
$true = true; // заданная и не пустая
unset($undefined); // не инициализированная/не заданная (unset() тоже, что ее и не было)
```

Вот как это выглядит в интерпетаторе php:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Т.е. мы видим, что если переменная не задана, то она **ВООБЩЕ ПУСТАЯ!**

**Результат функций isset, empty, is_null**:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

### Тогда в чем разница и где ее увидеть???

***При попытке обращения к неинициализированной переменной PHP отдаст значение `NULL` и сгенерирует `E_NOTICE` ошибку!***

Чтобы проверить существовала ли переменная или ей было задано значение `NULL` - нужно воспользоваться функцией `array_key_exists`:

- `array_key_exists('name_of_variable', $GLOBALS);` для проверки в глобальной области видимости
- `array_key_exists('name_of_variable', get_defined_vars());` для проверки в текущей области видимости

В текущем примере она сработает так:

```
array_key_exists('null', get_defined_vars()); // будет true
array_key_exists('undefined', get_defined_vars()); // будет false
```

### Теперь ответы на вопросы

> 1. Если мы используем неинициализированную переменную мы словим Notice, хотя в мануале написано что использовать неинициализированные переменные это очень хорошая практика, где?(Возможно это криво написано в мануале, возможно имелось ввиду наоборот)

В мануале написано, что хотя инициализировать и не обязательно, но считается хорошей практикой!

> 2. Если мы попытаемся к неициализированной переменной сделать допустим конкатенацию, мы словим Notice, хотя если мы напишем переменной изначально NULL, то Notice мы не словим, хотя опять же если мы выведем неинициализированную переменную через var_dump мы получим NULL...выходит в одном случае есть Notice, а в другом нет, почему?

Про разницу null и неициализированной написал выше.

> 3. Если мы присвоим переменной значение NULL будет ли считаться что переменная инициализированна? А если мы просто напишем переменную и в конце поставим точку с запятой будет ли это являться тем что переменная неинициализированна?(В мануале ни разу не видел чтобы просто писали переменную без присвоения)

Если присвоить NULL - да, она будет инициализированной.
Если просто напишем и в конце точка с запятой - нет, она так и будет неинициализированной.

Comment: Если я правильно понял, то различие состоит в том что если переменная неинициализирована и мы допустим вызываем `var_dump($a)`, то мы получим `Notice` из-за того что переменная не была инициализирована как-либо. А если переменная инициализирована `Null`, то есть `$a = NULL; var_dump($a);` то мы не получим `Notice` из-за того что переменная объявлена пустотой.
По факту первый `Null` показывает нам что такой переменной нет, а второй что переменная равна пустоте. Я правильно понял?

Comment: @MaximPro да, так и есть(по-сути хоть и так и так - NULL, но они как-бы разные NULL:D).

Comment: Ну тогда я думаю вопрос исчерпан =)
P.S Хороший ответ, видно старались, грех не наградить =)

Comment: @MaximPro ага :D

Comment: Наградить не могу, через 11 часов только